# Need help to create responsive two column full height div with vertical center content in one div and Image carouse in other div

Tags: jquery, html, css

i need to create responsive two-column full height div with vertical center content in right div and Image carouse full height and width in left div

[image: 1]

In mobile and tab screen it should be something like this -

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the code you are working with, to show what you have tried and make clear where the problem is. If not sure how to ask, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: welcome to SO @Shyjumon Thomas, it is always better to include your code snippet or a part of code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap class col-md-6 and col-sm-12 for responsive

-- or  --

use `@media` with min-screen

```
@media (min-width:1200px) {
            #image,#content {
                width: 50%;
                height: 100vh;
            }
        }

@media (min-width:768px) {
            #image{
                width: 100%;
                height: 30vh;
            }
            #content{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
```